# Detecting a timeout for a block of code in PHP

Tags: php, timeout

Is there a way you can abort a block of code if it's taking too long in PHP? Perhaps something like:

```
//Set the max time to 2 seconds
$time = new TimeOut(2);
$time->startTime();

sleep(3)

$time->endTime();
if ($time->timeExpired()){
    echo 'This function took too long to execute and was aborted.';
}
```

It doesn't have to be exactly like above, but are there any native PHP functions or classes that do something like this?

**Edit**: Ben Lee's answer with `pcnt_fork` would be the perfect solution except that it's not available for Windows. Is there any other way to accomplish this with PHP that works for Windows and Linux, but doesn't require an external library?

**Edit 2**: XzKto's solution works in some cases, but not consistently and I can't seem to catch the exception, no matter what I try. The use case is detecting a timeout for a unit test. If the test times out, I want to terminate it and then move on to the next test.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this by forking the process, and then using the parent process to monitor the child process. [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) is a method that forks the process, so you have two nearly identical programs in memory running in parallel. The only difference is that in one process, the parent, `pcntl_fork` returns a positive integer which corresponds to the process id of the child process. And in the other process, the child, `pcntl_fork` returns 0.

Here's an example:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
    // this is the child process
} else {
    // this is the parent process, and we know the child process id is in $pid
}
```

That's the basic structure. Next step is to add a process expiration. Your stuff will run in the child process, and the parent process will be responsible only for monitoring and timing the child process. But in order for one process (the parent) to kill another (the child), there needs to be a signal. Signals are how processes communicate, and the signal that means "you should end immediately" is SIGKILL. You can send this signal using [posix_kill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php). So the parent should just wait 2 seconds then kill the child, like so:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
    // this is the child process
    // run your potentially time-consuming method
} else {
    // this is the parent process, and we know the child process id is in $pid
    sleep(2); // wait 2 seconds
    posix_kill($pid, SIGKILL); // then kill the child
}
```

Comment: +1 - This would be a great solution as it's so simple, but unfortunately, I need something that works on both Windows and Linux (see the note: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php). Know of any other options?

Answer (score 11):

You can't really do that if you script pauses on one command (for example sleep()) besides forking, but there are a lot of work arounds for special cases: like asynchronous queries if you programm pauses on DB query, proc_open if you programm pauses at some external execution etc. Unfortunately they are all different so there is no general solution.

If you script waits for a long loop/many lines of code you can do a dirty trick like this:

```
declare(ticks=1);

class Timouter {

    private static $start_time = false,
    $timeout;

    public static function start($timeout) {
        self::$start_time = microtime(true);
        self::$timeout = (float) $timeout;
        register_tick_function(array('Timouter', 'tick'));
    }

    public static function end() {
        unregister_tick_function(array('Timouter', 'tick'));
    }

    public static function tick() {
        if ((microtime(true) - self::$start_time) > self::$timeout)
            throw new Exception;
    }

}

//Main code
try {
    //Start timeout
    Timouter::start(3);

    //Some long code to execute that you want to set timeout for.
    while (1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Timouter::end();
    echo "Timeouted!";
}
```

but I don't think it is very good. If you specify the exact case I think we can help you better.

Comment: +1 - This looks like it might work. However, I'm having trouble catching the exception...I suspect that it's because it's being thrown from a static method, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: So there isn't a problem with a static method throwing an exception by itself, just with this class. I can't seem to catch it at all, even with nested try/catch blocks. Any other exception I include in the try/catch is catchable. It does accomplish the timeout, though.

Comment: @VirtuosiMedia: could you please specify your OS and PHP version? I tested this code localy with PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5 and the exeption is always caught. This code is targeted for php version 5.3+ as this tick function was bugged for threaded enviroment before it (for example apache mod_php).

Comment: Note: The `declare(ticks=1)` should be specified in the script that calls the Timeouter class not the class file. Otherwise there is no ticks specified for the script itself therefore you never get exception.

Comment: Note 2: Does not timeout or tick while fetching through streams such as `file_get_contents($url);`

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, and has probably been solved many times by now, but for people looking for an easy way to solve this problem, there is a library now: [PHP Invoker](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/php-invoker).

Answer (score 3):

You can use declare function if the execution time exceeds the limits.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php

Here a code example of how to use

```
define("MAX_EXECUTION_TIME", 2); # seconds

$timeline = time() + MAX_EXECUTION_TIME;

function check_timeout()
{
    if( time() < $GLOBALS['timeline'] ) return;
    # timeout reached:
    print "Timeout!".PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

register_tick_function("check_timeout");
$data = "";

declare( ticks=1 ){
    # here the process that might require long execution time
    sleep(5); // Comment this line to see this data text
    $data = "Long process result".PHP_EOL;
}

# Ok, process completed, output the result:
print $data;
```

With this code you will see the timeout message.
If you want to get the Long process result inside the declare block you can just remove the sleep(5) line or increase the Max Execution Time declared at the start of the script

Answer (score 0):

What about [set-time-limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) if you are not in the safe mode.

Comment: Is there a way to unset the time limit after a particular block of code is done running? I just need the timeout for a section of code, not the whole script and I'd like to be able to detect the timeout without everything else failing.

Answer (score 0):

Cooked this up in about two minutes, I forgot to call `$time->startTime();` so I don't really know exactly how long it took ;)

```
class TimeOut{
    public function __construct($time=0)
    {
        $this->limit = $time;
    }

    public function startTime()
    {
        $this->old = microtime(true);
    }

    public function checkTime()
    {
        $this->new = microtime(true);
    }

    public function timeExpired()
    {
        $this->checkTime();
        return ($this->new - $this->old > $this->limit);
    }

}
```

And the **[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QF5nsz)**.

I don't really get what your `endTime()` call does, so I made `checkTime()` instead, which also serves no real purpose but to update the internal values. `timeExpired()` calls it automatically because it would sure stink if you forgot to call `checkTime()` and it was using the old times.

Comment: You mis-understood what the poster was asking for. He wants to time-limit a method's execution. His example was just pseudo-code. Your turning it into a class is not helpful.

Comment: "Doesn't have to be exactly like above" - Implies it can be. It functions just as OP requested, he can just run the `timeExpired` check in his method blocks. With my code, he can time-limit a method's execution indeed, and even has fine control over where execution should stop.

Comment: Well perhaps I misunderstood him, but it sounded like he was specifically asking for a solution that does not require him to call a time expired check (probably he does not have complete access to the internals of the method he needs to time limit). That's what his `endTime` implied...

Comment: Perhaps we should get OP to clarify then? I interpreted his question as asking for something that CAN perform that check, hence his pseudocode's checks being performed. If he hadn't wanted that, why would he ask for it?

Comment: Thanks for the help, Cyclone. To clarify, it was just psuedocode. @Ben Lee had it right what I was looking for.

Comment: I've reread the question multiple times, and I can't make it add up to his answer any way I figure it. Sorry I couldnt be of more help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a 2nd script that has the pause code in it that is executed via a curl call with a timeout set. The other obvious solution is to fix the cause of the pause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way to do that. Thanks to others answers:

```
<?php
class Timeouter
{
   private static $start_time = FALSE, $timeout;

   /**
    * @param   integer $seconds Time in seconds
    * @param null      $error_msg
    */
   public static function limit($seconds, $error_msg = NULL)
   : void
   {
      self::$start_time = microtime(TRUE);
      self::$timeout    = (float) $seconds;
      register_tick_function([ self::class, 'tick' ], $error_msg);
   }

   public static function end()
   : void
   {
      unregister_tick_function([ self::class, 'tick' ]);
   }

   public static function tick($error)
   : void
   {
      if ((microtime(TRUE) - self::$start_time) > self::$timeout) {
         throw new \RuntimeException($error ?? 'You code took too much time.');
      }
   }

   public static function step()
   : void
   {
      usleep(1);
   }
}
```

Then you can try like this:

```
  <?php
  try {
     //Start timeout
     Timeouter::limit(2, 'You code is heavy. Sorry.');

     //Some long code to execute that you want to set timeout for.
     declare(ticks=1) {
        foreach (range(1, 100000) as $x) {
           Timeouter::step(); // Not always necessary
           echo $x . "-";
        }
     }

     Timeouter::end();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
     Timeouter::end();
     echo $e->getMessage(); // 'You code is heavy. Sorry.'
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

I made a script in php using pcntl_fork and lockfile to control the execution of external calls doing the kill after the timeout.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

if(count($argv)<4){
    print "\n\n\n";
    print "./fork.php PATH \"COMMAND\" TIMEOUT\n"; // TIMEOUT IN SECS
    print "Example:\n";
    print "./fork.php /root/ \"php run.php\" 20";
    print "\n\n\n";
    die;
}

$PATH = $argv[1];
$LOCKFILE = $argv[1].$argv[2].".lock";
$TIMEOUT = (int)$argv[3];
$RUN = $argv[2];

chdir($PATH);


$fp = fopen($LOCKFILE,"w"); 
    if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
            print "Already Running\n";
            exit();
    }

$tasks = [
  "kill",
  "run",
];

function killChilds($pid,$signal) { 
    exec("ps -ef| awk '\$3 == '$pid' { print  \$2 }'", $output, $ret); 
    if($ret) return 'you need ps, grep, and awk'; 
    while(list(,$t) = each($output)) { 
            if ( $t != $pid && $t != posix_getpid()) { 
                    posix_kill($t, $signal);
            } 
    }    
} 

$pidmaster = getmypid();
print "Add PID: ".(string)$pidmaster." MASTER\n";

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    $pidslave = posix_getpid();
    if($pidslave != $pidmaster){
        print "Add PID: ".(string)$pidslave." ".strtoupper($task)."\n";
    }

  if ($pid == -1) {
    exit("Error forking...\n");
  }
  else if ($pid == 0) {
    execute_task($task);        
        exit();
  }
}

while(pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1);
echo "Do stuff after all parallel execution is complete.\n";
unlink($LOCKFILE);


function execute_task($task_id) {
    global $pidmaster;
    global $TIMEOUT;
    global $RUN;

    if($task_id=='kill'){
        print("SET TIMEOUT = ". (string)$TIMEOUT."\n");
        sleep($TIMEOUT);
        print("FINISHED BY TIMEOUT: ". (string)$TIMEOUT."\n");
        killChilds($pidmaster,SIGTERM);

        die;
  }elseif($task_id=='run'){
        ###############################################
        ### START EXECUTION CODE OR EXTERNAL SCRIPT ###
        ###############################################

            system($RUN);

        ################################    
        ###             END          ###
        ################################
        killChilds($pidmaster,SIGTERM);
        die;
    }
}
```

---

Test Script run.php

```
<?php

$i=0;
while($i<25){
    print "test... $i\n";
    $i++;
    sleep(1);
}
```