# PHP user defined timeout handling; but declare(ticks) is deprecated?

Tags: php

I am using following function to handle a timeout of a PHP script : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7498006 . The timeout is defined by myself and is independent of the normal max execution time.

This function works fine, although it is a bit annoying that `declare(ticks=1)` needs to be added to every single PHP file -- because the timeout functionality is implemented in a global shared include file.

The pages http://www.hackingwithphp.com/4/21/0/the-declare-function-and-ticks and http://www.w3resource.com/php/statement/declare.php write that "declare ticks" is deprecated starting with PHP 5.3 and will probably be removed in future PHP versions.

However, I could not see the deprecation warning on their official website: 
http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks

In case declare(ticks) is really deprecated, what can I alternative solution allows me to end after X seconds?